# Timestamp February shown as March

Tags: javascript, date

Good evening,

today i tried to compare some dates with Date in JavaScript. When I'm going to insert a timestamp, which is in February, it will be shown as March in external tools. For example:

```
var year = 2014;
var month = 2;
var day = 14;
var hour = 20;
var minute = 0;
var second = 0;
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0).getTime() / 1000;
```

This will return the value 1394823600 which is actually Friday, March 14, 2014 8:00:00 PM but not February.

Executed in Firefox v27.

Answer (score 6):

Because month index start at `0` where `0=January`, `1= Feb` and so on...`11=Decemeber`.